# Greasemonkey/User-Script Request: Remove "x" links next to “Interesting Tags”

Tags: discussion, tag-watching, userscript

For whatever reason, I have great difficulty with the *Interesting Tags*.  At least several times a week, I accidentally click the "x" next to a tag, removing it from the list.  It's probably because I'm an idiot or incapable of competently using a computer, but that's beside the point.

Anyway, I'm wondering if one of you Greasemonkey/JavaScript experts might be willing to write up a Chrome-compatible user script to remove the "x" links from the home page entirely.

I did a search for a script that did this, but I couldn't find anything.  My apologies if there is already a script out there to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the [alt text http://sstatic.net/mso/img/comment-del-hover.png](http://sstatic.net/mso/img/comment-del-hover.png) button completely:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SO Remove Interesting Tag Delete Button
// @namespace      StackOverflow
// @description    Removes the little red "X" next to the interesting tags
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){
  function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
      $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
    }
  }
  GM_wait();
  function letsJQuery() {
    $(function(){
        $('img.delete').hide();
        $('#interestingAdd').click(function(){ 
            $('img.delete').hide(); 
        });
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems JavaScript is officially at least 97% easier than when I last used it six years ago.  I couldn't get that script to run in Chrome; it just went into an infinite loop calling GM_Wait().  I copied the jquery.min.js source from Google into the top of the userscript and it works great.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @James - glad it works as I only tested in Firefox assuming it would work in both. You're right about JavaScript though - I avoided it as much as possible until Prototype (and now jQuery) significantly improved the ease of its use for web applications!

Comment: can this please be moved to http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts as necessary? Or flag for deletion.