# Add a confirmation dialog when trying to "Remove Interesting tag"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

It has happened a number of times that I accidentally remove an interesting tag. Seems [I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/greasemonkey-user-script-request-remove-x-links-next-to-interesting-tags). I add the tag again, but it is now in a new position, and this is teasing.

Could a javascript confirmation (`confirm(..)`) be added on the remove button?

Comment: I took the liberty of applying this to ignored tags as well -- if you don't think that's appropriate, feel free to edit.

Comment: And now the very heart of my name has been bisected, cut straight in twain by @Popular!

Comment: I want this feature too. Add the program language "C" as your tag, and there's a bigger chance that you remove the tag than list the posts each time you click it...

Comment: This continues to annoy me. I don't know how many times I have removed a favorite while simply trying to view them. I have clicked related and linked questions, cannot see where this has been otherwise addressed.

Comment: If its not fixed by tomorrow, i'll userscript it!

Comment: [Duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827) [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704) [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350) [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29584)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confirm dialog when an interesting (or ignored) tag is to be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/confirm-dialog-when-an-interesting-or-ignored-tag-is-to-be-deleted)