# Can margins or padding be increased between tag name and "remove tag" icon in Favorite Tags?

Tags: feature-request, design

Following the implementation [of this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags) to move the "remove tag" icon into the tag's container in `Favorite Tags` & `Ignored Tags`, the target clickable area for short tags becomes very small.  I frequently find myself accidentally removing my [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) tags by clicking too near to the "remove" icon.

[Here was proposed a JavaScript confirmation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51138/remove-interesting-tag-confirmation) popup to confirm removal (no answers).  I would request an even simpler implementation to simply increase the margins or right-padding between the tag text and the remove icon to enlarge the clickable region of the tag's text.

My mouse pointer did not appear in the image below, but it was just right of the `l` at the pixel edge of the remove icon, approximately in the center of the tag button. As seen below, the remove icon is highlighted in this position and a click would result in the removal of this tag.

[image: Close icon is too close to tag text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply made a [Chrome extension](https://bitbucket.org/miorga/stackoverflow-no-delete-tag/src) that moves the `X` on right-top corner like this:

> [image: Delete Icon]

Answer (score 5):

[This problem gets much (!) worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149453/1968) with one-letter tags such as [r](/questions/tagged/r). The clickable area here is simply too little:

[image: screenshot]

In case it’s not obvious: the clickable area of the “delete” button is bigger than that of the “r”.