# Bigger Tag for R in Stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can margins or padding be increased between tag name and “remove tag” icon in Favorite Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115739/can-margins-or-padding-be-increased-between-tag-name-and-remove-tag-icon-in-fa)

This is a question to the moderators of stackoverflow!

Would you please assign a bit of more space for R tag in your website?

I just tried to click on the tag, but removed it :-)

Comment: You can always use the `rstats` tag that is a synonym --5 more characters!

Comment: Perhaps they need to get themselves a [sponsored](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) tag [icon](http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg)

Comment: @Lix Didn't think that was free for open-source tools. R is free as in beer, so who's going to pay that?

Comment: Forcing lower case make this even worse.  It's not even an `R` tag but an `r` tag (which is worse still in the proportional font used for tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the tag is small because it consists of a single letter. I do agree that it might be beneficial to have a larger padding on tags in general; at the moment it’s not very clickable.

Comment: Especially on my tablet I have a hard time not deleting the tag