# Increase the minimum tag box width

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, design

I have a problem with tags which consist of only 1 character like [r](/questions/tagged/r). When I add such a tag to my favorite tags and try to click on it, I almost always mistakenly click on the 'x' and delete my favorite tag. This is because the tag width is so short (the area 'x' covers is larger than the one tag name does itself).

[image]

Could you please increase the minimum tag box width to solve this problem?

Comment: [Can margins or padding be increased between tag name and “remove tag” icon in Favorite Tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115739/187824)

Comment: I do this .. way to many times, and the favorite tags get rearranged, I add again that tag .. and I tend to click in same place were it was last time.

Comment: @Mehper yes, agree with you, most of the time, by mistake i click on the "x" rather than on [tag:c] and then i have to add that rag again :(

Comment: You can use [my extension](https://bitbucket.org/miorga/stackoverflow-no-delete-tag/src), it moves the `X` on top-right corner.