# Make it harder to delete favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Remove Interesting tag” confirmation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51138/remove-interesting-tag-confirmation)

Reading on a small touch screen it is far too easy to fat finger that little red x and the tag is just gone.

Could there be a way to lock them, or require confirmation?

Comment: This is obviously to discourage C programmers, and make them choose a language where the red x isn't 75% of the tag.

Comment: sorry about the duplicate -- (or 3 or 4 x ) .  However I really meant this as a feature request and i don't consider installing toolbars in every browser a satisfactory solution.